# How to select a node's first child name? XPath

Tags: xpath, children

I have an XML from which I have to select the name of the child of one of the nodes. I'm kind of a beginner in this, so I didn't find the Xpath expression to do it. I know the level of the node

**Example**

Name from `/Employee/Department/`

but Department has children nodes of unknown names. I have to select the first child of Department node. How can I do this?

Comment: Could someone add the 'child' tag? I had trouble finding this question and it helped me a lot. Adding it requires 1500 repuation hence I can't do it.

Answer (score 76):

You wrote:

> I have to select the first child of
>   Department node

You could use:

```
/Employee/Department/*[1]
```

Then, you also wrote:

> I have an XML from which I have to
>   select the name of the child of one of
>   the nodes

So, you could use:

```
name(/Employee/Department/*[1])
```

Comment: +1. This is assuming that the OP wants the first *element* child, which is probably a valid assumption.

Answer (score 25):

I don't know the exact context of your XML, but I believe this is the XPath you are looking for...

```
/Employee/Department/*[1]
```

The key part of this XPath is `*[1]`, which will select the node value of the first child of `Department`.

If you need the name of the node, then you will want to use this...

```
name(/Employee/Department/*[1])
```

Answer (score 10):

You need something like:

```
local-name(/Employee/Department/*[1])
```